# How to sort results from ls command by modification date (directories first)?

Tags: linux, bash, ls, sort

I can fire

```
ls -lrt
```

to get files and folders sorted by modification date, but this does not separate directories from files. I want `ls` to show me first directories by modification date and then files by modification date. How to do that?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

what about something like this:

```
ls -ltr --group-directories-first
```

Comment: Great, thanks! Somehow I was not able to find this from the man page. My bad, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

`ls -t`

or (for reverse, most recent at bottom):

`ls -tr`

The [`ls` man page](http://ss64.com/bash/ls.html) describes this in more details, and lists other options.

Directories have `d` in front of there permissions in `ls -ltr`

So to get **directories** with sorted modification date use

`ls -ltr |grep ^d`

And to **files other than directories**

`ls -ltr | grep -v ^d`

Comment: No, this does not produce the correct result.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/147027/how-can-i-sort-the-output-of-ls-by-last-modified-date

Comment: You are correct about folders, I updated question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but if you read my question carefully, you might notice that I already know how to sort ls output by modification date (ls -lrt), but not how to sort results so that I get directories first by mod date and then files by mod date.

Comment: hey jrara i have got your question.. i am getting back with the answer...